# Trialforce and Opportunity Created Date

Tags: trialforce

When I create a new Dev or Sandbox org for and import data, I can enabling "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" which allows the Opp Created Date to be updated with any value. If I don't enable those fields, the Opp Created Date will be the date/time of record update.

But when I create a new Demo Org using a TSO Template (with various Opp Created Date values), all Opp Created Dates are the org creation date/time .

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a new Test/Demo org using a Trialforce Template ID, but first unlocking the Opp Created Date to allow values from the TSO?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes I have about Trialforce (from a few years ago) say:

- Use the Setup -> Trialforce -> New Organization Template (only available in the master org)
- Uncheck the **Adjust All Dates in the Resulting Organization Relative to Organization Creation Date** checkbox

implying that the choice is made when the template is created not when the new org is created from the template.